# Unable to send dataframe to oracle. (Export dataframe to oracle)

Tags: database, pandas, oracle, dataframe, pandas-to-sql

**Unable to send data from pandas (Dataframe) to oracle database.**

```
engine = create_engine('oracle+cx_oracle://username:password@localhost')
    
        dataset.to_sql(
            name='table_name',
            con=engine,
            if_exists='append',
            index=False
        )
```

Comment: you need to specify your schema i.e `name='customer', schema='dim'`

Comment: so customer is table name and schema is your schema name right? and where should i write this code in create_engine or dataset,to_sql?

Comment: see [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html) in the documentation, it has all you need.

Comment: when you say 'unable to send...', you mean you get an error? you cannot find your data afterwards? ....If you get an error, what is it?

Comment: It's taking too much time to upload i think.